# Anyone can recommend proper AWS license to perform sentiment analysis?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am recently doing some sentiment research using twitter data. But the the number of tweets are **115,929,358**.. So I am thinking to use AWS, I have no clue which type of license I should purchase... Anyone can recommend which type of AWS is good to purchase or other options?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't buy licences to use AWS software. It's all [pay as you go](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/) and stop any time.

For analyzing sentiment in text, see [Amazon Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/analyze-sentiment-comprehend/) and its [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/pricing/).